# Maven Plugin Working Directory Not Constant

Tags: file, maven, plugins, maven-2, classpath

I wrote a Maven Plugin that creates some XML files on the classpath of my project.   The Maven Project is fairly complex and has one master project with many sub projects (think services for a larger application).

The plugin takes a directory argument in the pom.xml, which is something relative to the classpath like this:

```
<docDestination>src/main/webapp/static/</docDestination>
```

However, when I try to access this folder via `new File(docDestination)`, the resulting directory depends on the project (or sub-project) from which I ran the `mvn install` command that triggered the plugin.

The plugin is only specified in the `pom.xml` of one of the sub-projects, but if I run mvn-install from the parent it creates the XML files in the `src/main/...` folder of the parent application.  How do I get the plugin to use the filesystem of the project in which it is declared rather than the filesystem of the parent project?

I should note that if I navigate to the sub-project in Terminal and run `mvn install` in that directory the files are created in the right place, which explains the title of my post.

Comment: I think you missed to add the basedir of the current project which can as far as i know inherited by the injected maven parameters (MavenProject?). Otherwise you can change the configuration into ${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ${basedir} variable:

```
<docDestination>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/static</docDestination>
```

This should use the basedir currently used by the respective module (regardless of whether this is the top-level or a sub-module).

Comment: Thank you so much, you nailed it in less than 15 minutes.  SO should have a speed reward.